# How to get maximum value of one entity in nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
people = {1: {'Name': 'John', 'Age': '22', 'Sex': 'Male'}, 2: {'Name': 'Marie', 'Age': '26', 'Sex': 'Female'}, 3: {'Name': 'Marie', 'Age': '25', 'Sex': 'Female'}, 4: {'Name': 'Marie', 'Age': '21', 'Sex': 'Female'}}
```

I want to get the maximum value of 'Age'. Kindly help me how to do this.

Comment: Do a loop and look for it

Comment: convert to a pandas dataframe and then get the maximum of `age` using numpy. Easy

Comment: @Trishna, there is a pandas way of doing this but that wouldn't be efficient solution for this, its better to loop through and find the maximum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `max` with a defined key and `lambda`.

```
people = {1: {'Name': 'John', 'Age': '22', 'Sex': 'Male'}, 2: {'Name': 'Marie', 'Age': '26', 'Sex': 'Female'}, 3: {'Name': 'Marie', 'Age': '25', 'Sex': 'Female'}, 4: {'Name': 'Marie', 'Age': '21', 'Sex': 'Female'}}
max(people.values(), key=lambda x: int(x['Age']))
# {'Name': 'Marie', 'Age': '26', 'Sex': 'Female'}

max(people.values(), key=lambda x: int(x['Age']))['Age']
# '26'
```

Comment: booo lambda boooo

Comment: I guess you want to convert the age to `int`

Comment: @SuperStew why?

Comment: @I'mahdi Thank you for your help. I got the value.

Comment: @NicholasFeruch they have their use cases, but they're too non-pythonic for relatively simple tasks like this

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted just the max value then `max` with a generator would suffice

```py
people = {1: {'Name': 'John', 'Age': '22', 'Sex': 'Male'}, 2: {'Name': 'Marie', 'Age': '26', 'Sex': 'Female'}, 3: {'Name': 'Marie', 'Age': '25', 'Sex': 'Female'}, 4: {'Name': 'Marie', 'Age': '21', 'Sex': 'Female'}}
result = max(int(p['Age']) for p in people.values())
```

Which I prefer over the lambda, however if you want the dictionary that has the max Age then @I'mahdi answer is what you want.